# Custom blending equations (shader) for OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, alphablending

I am trying to experiment with different alpha blending equations for transparent objects using OpenGL but it looks like fragment shaders operate on the color of fragments on single objects and cant take into account the scene behind the object.

On the other hand there doesn't seem to be a way to intercept the [blending stage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) with arbitrary GLSL code, for example I can't think of a way to reproduce [soft light blend mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Soft_Light) with the current OpenGL primitives.

Is there a way to reconcile these?

Comment: If you need a complex blending function, you can render into a texture. Then, in a second pass, in your fragment shader you can query from that texture which represents the previous rendered object, and do the blending on your own. The issue is that you need a `glDraw*` call for each object, plus another one to blit the texture to the frame buffer. Perhaps using atomic operations with SSBO is better.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple relatively well-supported extensions:

- [KHR_blend_equation_advanced](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/KHR/KHR_blend_equation_advanced.txt) - implements common blending modes (including soft light).
- [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) - provides destination color from the framebuffer for fully custom blending in the shader.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to call framebuffer fetch "well-supported", considering that [only Intel hardware supports it.](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch) And not even most Intel hardware at that.

Comment: @NicolBolas Mali, Tegra and whatever's in the iPhone also support it (maybe with a different prefix).

Comment: I'm sure they do. But since the question is tagged for OpenGL, never mentions OpenGL *ES*, and those GPUs only provide OpenGL ES, they're not really relevant to this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Blending is still one of those few parts of the fragment pipeline that's a hardwired circuit on the GPU. Hence it's not programmable. Your best bet is rendering to a texture and do a blending postprocessing pass.

Answer (score 0):

copy render target, and draw your object with it as texture.

if there is many small object, you can only copy part of your render target.

first pass:  draw object with render target as texture to texture_2;

second pass: draw object to render target with texture_2;